# How would I convert this excel formula into a MS Access or VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Trying to convert this MS Excel formula

```
=IF((D2+C3)>0,0,(D2+C3))
```

How would I convert it into MS Access or VBA?

This is the dataset table in Excel that we are importing into Access

[image]

Comment: What is D2 and C3?  Do you have a table in Access?

Comment: FYI, the Access "IIF" function, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3, is essentially the same as the excel "IF" function.

Comment: I added the Picture of the dataset

Comment: What are the column names you are trying to use?  Is this a table in your access database?

Comment: Did you already import it?  How are you connecting between excel and access?

Comment: See here to add a calculated field, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3

Comment: The problem using the calculated field it will not take the previous day above into account. The "Bucket" column is the already calculated field in Excel. We are trying to automate a ms access database and convert this formula =IF((D2+C3)>0,0,(D2+C3)) into MS Access.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now.  See here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290136

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a `lag` function, which is not native to MS Access.  If your data actually resides in a linked database, the majority of them do have `lag`, and you could accomplish this via a pass-thru.  There is a clever (although not efficient) hack to accomplish a lag, but it requires a primary key and some other circumstances to work.  If you have all of that, perhaps update your question to reflect this...  since this is Excel, I'm betting not, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

=IIF(([Rollover]+[Bucket])>0,0,([Rollover]+[Bucket]))

Although, your Excel formula references D2 and C3, in different rows. That's going to be a bit tricky in Access if that's what you really need to do. It is possible to do, if that's what you really want, but you may need to add a ROW Number field (or an autonumber ID field) in order to do that.

Blair

Editted: (since I just read the "see more comments")

The quick and dirty way to do this is to add the RowNumber field, the make a query from the dataset with a calculated field output NextRowNumber: [RowNumber]+1. Link the query and the dataset together with RowNumber and NextRowNumber. Use the [Rollover] field from the query ([Query]![Rollover] and the [Bucket] field from the dataset ([dataset]![Bucket]) in the equation above.

There is likely a more elegant way to do this in VBA, but the linked query / dataset should work.

Blair

Comment: This was it. I added the row number and linked them off of the rownumber+1 as you suggested and i was able to get them at least in the same row to add an IIF statement that worked for my situation.